# ¿Por qué la opción de Iniciar Depuración - Iniciar sin depuración aparace en gris y no se puede seleccionar?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, depuración

[image: "Iniciar depuración" e "Iniciar sin depurar" Aparece en gris y no se pueden seleccionar]

Me descargué Visual Studio 2019, lo probé y todo iba bien, pero cuando quise probar el programa a ver qué tal, veo que no me deja depurar. Llevo buscando soluciones, pero parece que a nadie le ha pasado esto. ¿Alguno sabe cómo solucionarlo?

Comment: Hechale un ojo a esto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398767/f5-or-start-debugging-button-is-greyed-out-for-winform-application

Comment: @AbrahamChan eso no es mejor una respuesta a la pregunta? :)

Answer (score 0):

Para poder ejecutar una prueba, es necesario agregar un proyecto a tu solución. Para esto los siguientes pasos son:

**click derecho en el nombre de tu solución -> agregar -> nuevo proyecto...**

seleccionas el tipo de proyecto (por el código que veo en la imagen: aplicación de consola) y al crear la aplicación se te activan las opciones de depuración.

Toma en cuenta que las clases deben estar dentro del nuevo proyecto.

Comment: No me sirvió. Creo un nuevo proyecto desde mi solución, pero a la derecha no se ve nada, sigue estando como se ve en la foto y sigo sin poder depurar...

Comment: Quizá sea un detalle con la instalación, prueba abrir el programa Visual Studio Installer, en Visual Studio 2019 de las modificar, vas a la opción desarrollo de escritorio de .Net y seleccionas las opciones de herramientas de desarrollo de .NET,Framework, debes tener tantas herramientas de desarrollo como versiones de .Net Frameworks con los que planees trabajar

Comment: No, tengo todas esas herramientas.